# R: Best models for grouped data with factor and numeric independent variables. (not bio data)

Tags: r, modeling

What would be the best model for data with grouped, and its independent variables are factor & numeric.

I used regression decision tree but turned out not accurate enough, and which can make sense, since the data has groups in it. ANOVA can apply for the data with only factor independent variables only, so I tried Mixed effect model.

**Can Mixed Effect Model be applied  to the data with factor & numeric independent variable? If so the model below make sense?**

```
> mod<-lmer(dollar~workhour+num.product+
+          (1+num.product|types)+
+          (1|jobID),
+           data=sample)
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
Warning message:
Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling
```

**If we can't apply Mixed Effect Model, what model do you think would work for the data?**

(My original data sets have 40-70 rows and each data set is about separate projects, and I plan to build models for the separate projects. Below sample has the same format as the original, but shorter)

```
data

dollar<-c(10000,1200,3600,900,10000,2000,5000,6000,4000,1000,20000,1000,2000,1000)
jobID<-as.factor(c(1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,10,10,10,4,4))
types<-c('material','labor',"gas",'extra','material',"labor","labor",'supply','gas', 'labor',
    'material','extra','extra','extra')
workhour<-c(0,1600,0,0,0,12000,20000,0,0,310,0,0,0,0) # work minutes
num.product<-c(5,5,5,5,14,14,14,14,14,6,6,6,0,0)      # number of produced products
year<-as.factor(c(2017,2017,2017,2017,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019))
```

Comment: ANOVA can apply for the data with only factor independent variables only... this is not true. you can use anove with fixed effect, both categorical and continuous

Comment: @StupidWolf thank you so much, then do you think what would be good fixed and random for this data?

Comment: Hey @rocknRrr, it's more like how you want to model the data, you can read this discussion, https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2005/01/25/why_i_dont_use/, one way you can do it is to have variables of interest under fixed effect, and nuisance parameters under random.. So in your formula, for example, why is the motivation behind specifying a randoms slope with (1+num.product|types) ?

Comment: In most situations, if you want to do infer something about a parameter, a normal linear model might be ok.. maybe you can elaborate more on what you want to get from the model